# TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index when applying a custom function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, apply

I want to apply a function on groups of a data frame and get the function output as a new column.

Here is the function that I wrote:

```
def get_centroids(sample):
    
    # Ideally, re = complex_function(sample) that returns 1d array which has the same length as sample
    # for simplicity let's use np.random.rand(len(sample))

    re = pd.DataFrame({'B': np.random.rand(len(sample))})
    print(re)
    print(re.index)  
    return re
```

The function prints,

```
   B
0  0.176083
1  0.984371

RangeIndex(start=0, stop=2, step=1)
```

Let's look at this data frame. For simplicity, it has only one group 'a'.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': 'a a'.split(),
                   'B': [1,43],
                   'C': [4,2]})

    A   B   C
0   a   1   4
1   a   43  2

print(df.index)
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=2, step=1)
```

When I apply the function as below,

```
df['test'] = df.groupby('A')[['B']].apply(get_centroids)
```

it throws "TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index" though df and re has the similar type of indexes. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try passing `group_keys=False` to `groupby` and please see the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html?highlight=group_keys) & experiment with `group_keys` parameter via printing groupby result without assigning it to a column.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I gave a quick try with group_keys=False, but it still gives the same error. I will dig more with it.

Comment: I tried but it didn't give any error: `df["test"] = df.groupby("A", group_keys=False)[["B"]].apply(get_centroids)` on the sample data you provided above.

Comment: Thanks mate! But it still throws the error... did you run the entire statement? as in altogether with df["test"] =

Comment: Yes the entire statement and no error. I use pandas version 1.2.4.

Comment: Mine is 1.1.2. However, I tried with the version 1.2.4 in here (https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/online-compiler/), but still throws the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I was playing around with the suggestions, I realised that `df.groupby('A')[['B']].apply(get_centroids)` alone works fine, and the assignment causes the error.

In other words, `df` does not receive well `df.groupby('A')[['B']].apply(get_centroids)`. I then decided to check for `df.groupby('A')[['B']].apply(get_centroids).index` which is

```
MultiIndex([('a', 0),
            ('a', 1)],
           names=['A', None])
```

The index of `df` was `RangeIndex(start=0, stop=2, step=1)`. Therefore, `RangeIndex` vs `MultiIndex` mismatach caused the issue.

This can be solved by resetting and setting the index of `df.groupby('A')[['B']].apply(get_centroids)` as below.

```
df['test'] = df.groupby('A')[['B']].apply(get_centroids).reset_index().set_index('level_1').drop('A',axis=1)
```

The same solution has been proposed here https://stackoverflow.com/a/66709059/8561039.